# При обработке события TextChanged , ComboBox Меняет selectedIndex и подставляет значение

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Предыстория:
Насколько я сумел убедиться ComboBox не имеет возможности контекстного поиска в каждом элементе из собственного списка. Поэтому добавил несложный алгоритм метод (FillDBList) который отбирает элементы содержащие введенные пользователем символы, в любой части поля.

```
    private void DataBase_ComboBox_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(DataBase_ComboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        string curText = DataBase_ComboBox.Text;
        //MessageBox.Show(DataBase_ComboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        DataBase_ComboBox.DroppedDown = false;
        DataBase_ComboBox.Items.Clear();
        DataBase_ComboBox.Items.AddRange(FillDBList(curText));

        //DataBase_ComboBox.SelectedText = "";
        //MessageBox.Show(DataBase_ComboBox.Text);
        DataBase_ComboBox.SelectionStart = DataBase_ComboBox.Text.Length;
        //DataBase_ComboBox.
        DataBase_ComboBox.DroppedDown = true;
        MessageBox.Show(DataBase_ComboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    }
```

Пробовал аналогично обработать событие TextChanged но разницы нет ComboBox по какой-то не видимой причине меняет значение DataBase_ComboBox.Text(сам выбирает значение из списка) в соответствии с введенным символом, а потом дергается SelectedIndexChanged. Поведение похоже на работу AutoCompleteMode, только этот режим отключен.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с проблемой? Или может есть иные варианты решения этой задачи?

Comment: может потому, что тут `DataBase_ComboBox.Items.Clear();` вы удаляете все элементы из комбобокса, вместе с тем, который был выбран?

Comment: дело в том, что этот функционал я заложил ранее для того, чтобы перезаполнять список элементами из метода FillDBList() который возвращает результат поиска. То есть как бы список обновляется на каждый введенный символ, и фактически суть проблемы в том, что изначально DataBase_ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 , то есть элемент не выбран, но он почему то выбирается неявно при описании обработчика события "DataBase_ComboBox_TextUpdate"